# How can i access data of one application in another application using Content Providers

Tags: android

I have two applications A and B, In application A suppose i am using ipdetails.db file and saving IP address in the iptable.

In Application A i am using Content Resolver(I used all methods provided in some examples of Content Provider) and other classes to access the data.

Now my question is In Application B i have transaction.db file with some tables how can i get ip details from application A using content providers.

Getting data from Content Providers with same application i succeeded how can i access data of One application in Another application.

I am waiting for your valuable inputs...

Answer (score 1):

**ProjectOne:**

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".ProjectTwoActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.zetsin.test.MYACTION" /> 
            <data android:scheme="info"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

and *MainActivityInProjectOne.java*

```
    // getIntent().getData() is get the url form ProjectTwo
    if (getIntent().getData() != null) { 
        // get the data passed from ProjectTwo
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
    }
```

**ProjectTwo:**

*MainActivityInProjectTwo.java*

```
    // start the activity in ProjectOne by Action and URI, then pass the data.
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("info://test"); 
    Intent invokeIntent = new Intent("com.zetsin.test.MYACTION",uri); 
    invokeIntent.putExtra("value", "Data from project Two"); 
    startActivity(invokeIntent);
```

Comment: If i use above code Project One is not launching,If you don't mind can you please update me indetail